# Par: justify text without joining lines

Tags: formatting, format, alignment

Par is a great tool to format text.

Par joins text and format it to the new size.

Can Par also justify text without joining lines?

p.e.

```
text text text text
text2 text2 text2 text2
txt txt txt txt txt
```

justify to 30

```
text     text     text    text
text2   text2   text2    text2
txt    txt    txt    txt   txt
```

I've read the manual without finding the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the nearest you can get with `par` is to use the `j1` option in conjunction with a very carefully chosen `w` value.

From http://www.nicemice.net/par/par-doc.var

```
j[<just>]   If <just> is 1, par justifies the OP, inserting spaces
            between words so that all lines in the OP have length
            <width> (except the last, if <last> is 0).  Defaults to
            0.  (See also the w, l, and f options.)
```

---

`par` behaves rather pathalogically with your example text, I think it incorrectly detects a line prefix.

```
$ cat test2.txt
text text text text
text2 text2 text2 text2
txt txt txt txt txt
```

The best I could get out of it was

```
$ ./par -w23 -j1 -p0 -h0 <test2.txt
text  text   text  text
text2 text2 text2 text2
txt txt txt txt txt
```

---

I think I'd try `perl`, with maybe [Text::Autoformat](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Text-Autoformat-1.669006/lib/Text/Autoformat.pm) and feed `autoformat` one line at a time.

---

That idea led me to the rather ugly but fairly effective

```
$ perl -pe 's/$/\r\n123456789 123456789 123456789 /;' test2.txt| \
> ./par -w30 -j1 -l1 -p0 -h0 | \
> perl -ne 'print unless /^123456789 123456789 123456789 $/'
text    text     text    text
text2   text2   text2   text2
txt    txt   txt    txt   txt
```

I can't help feeling that a far more elegant solution is available.

Comment: Tnx for answering. I tried `par 30j1` but that doesn't give the expected results. It still joins the lines.

Comment: @Remonn: updated.